# Running the same code for many tibbles in the global environment in R

Tags: r

I am working with R.

I have many tibbles that look similar to this (I say similar because they contain 5 columns at the beginning and 11 columns at the and that need to be eliminated)

```
chair   table  hill  block  chain  ball  money house

  2       4     5      6      7     -2     4     5 
  1       3     6      1      8      3     9     1
 -2       1     1     -2      1      8    -2     3
  6       4    -2      4     -2      5     8     4
  5       5     5      5      3      2     6     7
```

First I need to eliminate the columns that I don't need at the beginning and at the end of the tibble. So, I used this code.

```
dummy1 <- at01 %>% 
  select(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -name, -time, -id, -class,
         -slot, -bracket, -app, -aal, -PHT, -END,
         -START)
```

Then, I need to rename the columns by eliminating the first 4 characters of the column names with this code.

```
names(dummy1) <- substring(names(dummy1), 5)
```

And, finally, I need to replace all the -2 with NA's

```
dummy1[dummy1 == -2] <- NA
```

I have 120 documents in my global environment. How can I pass all the code in order to obtain clean results rapidly without the need of doing these three steps with every tibble.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applying the same functions to multiple dataframes, it is easiest to work with them in a list, so that you can use functions from `apply` or `purrr`. Here, I am assuming that only the 120 dataframes are in your global environment. I first put all dataframes in your global environment into a list. Then, we can apply your various functions (I put it all into one function) on each dataframe to clean them up. Then, you can apply that function using `purrr::map` to each dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Put all dataframes in your global environment into a list.
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

cleanup <- function(x){
  x <- x %>% 
    select(-c(1:5, name, time, id, class,
           slot, bracket, app, aal, PHT, END,
           START)) %>% 
    mutate_all(~replace(., . == -2, NA))
  
  names(x) <- substring(names(x), 5)
  return(x)
}

dfs_cleanedup <- purrr::map(dfs, cleanup)
```

Then, if you want to overwrite the 120 dataframes in your global environment with the cleaned dataframes, then you can do something like this (**Caution**: it will overwrite the dataframes in the global environment).

```
list2env(dfs_cleanedup, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```